# How do I use jsmad?

Tags: javascript, audio, mp3, audio-streaming, html5-audio

jsmad is a new JavaScript based MP3 decoder ([GitHub](https://github.com/nddrylliog/jsmad), [demo](http://jsmad.org/)), but it seems to be lacking any documentation at all. I can't really work out what a lot of the demo is doing either, and the actual JavaScript seems minified.

Is anyone able to write up some documentation here for someone that just wants to play MP3 audio, please? It looks like [a few people are giving up because of the lack of documentation](https://github.com/nddrylliog/jsmad/issues/7).

Comment: Also, could someone with enough reputation create a jsmad tag for this question? It seems appropriate, but I don't have the rep for it.

Comment: We do not need a tag for every single library on the planet, especially those that have very searchable names.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. I just figured that was what the point of tags were.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sent an email over to Amos Wenger, one of the developers for jsmad, who had this to say:

> Hi there!
>
> Yes, we are very much aware of the lack of documentation. There are
>   two reasons for that:
>
> First, the bad news: jsmad only does MP3 -> raw audio, whereas people
>   expect a much more complete piece of software (similar to HTML5 audio,
>   which does HTTP streaming, buffering, decoding, audio sink, UI
>   controls, events etc.) As I mentioned in my jsmad slides at jsconf.eu,
>   we need to flesh out several other components before we have a real
>   competitor for Flash-based audio playback on your website. So in a
>   way, the lack of docs is because we don't want end-users to start
>   deploying it on their website just yet! It's not ready for prime time.
>
> At ofmlabs (Official.fm's R&D division, among other stuff) we had a
>   lot of internal projects going on, and have only recently been able to
>   re-focus on open source. So that's the good news: we'll have more time
>   to spend on stuff like jsmad, and will probably work on the missing
>   parts (buffering, proper demuxing - probably via aurora.js, etc.)
>
> As for 'docs', there are a little in my slides (mentioned above), and
>   well mhd.js is not minified so you can always take a look at
>   http://jsmad.org/mhd.js ;)
>
> Cheers, Amos

So it looks like jsmad isn't up for public use just yet, but we can look forward to further support in the future. :)